# How to add [...] in displayquote environment

Tags: csquotes

I am trying to add [...] in displayquote environment, but instead I am getting a weird result :

```
\begin{displayquote}
[...]feedback was least effective when it focused on the task in hand, 
and more effective when it focused on the details at hand, and most
effective when it focused on the details of the task and involved
goal-setting (\citeNP[s. 140]{will10})
\end{displayquote}
```

Here is the output I am getting :

> feedback was least effective when it focused on the task in hand, and
>   more effective when it focused on the details at hand, and most
>   effective when it focused on the details of the task and involved
>   goal-setting. (William, 2010, s. 140) (...)

How can I add the syntax [...] in the quote?

Here is a "minimal code example":

**Main file (links subfiles, i.e chapters - file name : main.tex)**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{jneurosci}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\MakePerPage{footnote}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figur}
}

\makeatletter
\def\@documentnocite#1{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#1\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
    \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\G@refundefinedtrue
      \@latex@warning{Citation `\@citeb' undefined}}{}}%
  \@esphack}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\nocite\@documentnocite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 

\subfile{chapter3}

\subfile{biblo}

\end{document}
```

**Chapter where I am trying to quote with [...] (file name chapter3.tex)**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles} 
\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}
[...]feedback was least effective when it focused on the task in hand, and more effective when it focused on the details
at hand, and most effective when it focused on the details of the task and involved goal-setting.
(\citeNP[s. 140]{will10})
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

**The bibliography (file name : biblo.tex) :**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles} 

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{database}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

**The database for the bibliography (file name : database.bib) :**

```
@incollection{will10,
  author  = "Dylan William",
  editor  = "H. Dumont and D. Istance and F. Benavides",
  title   = "The {R}ole of {F}ormative {A}ssessments in {E}ffective {L}earning {E}nvironments",
  booktitle = "{T}he {N}ature og {L}earning. {U}sing {R}esearch to {I}nspire {P}ractice.",
  year = "2010",
  pages = "153--159",
  isbn = 9789264086470,
  publisher = "{O}{E}{C}{D} {P}ublishing"
}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Moriambar You are right, it was a in the pain *** :)

Comment: `\begin{displayquote}\relax`: the environment is looking for an optional argument. Remove `\usepackage{a4}` and pass instead the `a4paper` option to `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific command for the `csquotes` defined environment to print the ellipsis, and it is `\textelp`. You could investigate it further in the package documentation.

Nevertheless

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn,a4]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{jneurosci}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\MakePerPage{footnote}

\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figur}
}

\makeatletter
\def\@documentnocite#1{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#1\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
    \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\G@refundefinedtrue
      \@latex@warning{Citation `\@citeb' undefined}}{}}%
  \@esphack}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\nocite\@documentnocite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}[]
\textelp{} feedback was least effective when it focused on the task in hand, and more effective when it focused on the details
at hand, and most effective when it focused on the details of the task and involved goal-setting.
(\citeNP[s. 140]{will10})
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

Prints:

[image]

Comment: So it turned out that I did not need to paste all that code ^^. \textelp{} brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: @imranal the code was too much, but nevertheless knowing that you had no other packages conflicting and so on couldn't be determined otherwise. By removing what is superfluous for the specific problem you can also determine by yourself if anything is wrong in some of the packages; it's good practice!

Comment: The problem with people like me (i.e. we mortals who barely manage to compile tex code) is that we do not know what is too much and too little code example. I feel sorry for you guys, I truly do. Keep up the saintly work!

Comment: @imranal I think that one rule of thumb could be: give all the packages you have, and the part of the document that causes the problem, enclosed in `begin{document}` … `\end{document}`. If that works you discovered something interesting; otherwise the community will help you.